# No WriteResult returned in Mongo shell when inserting/updating a row in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am able to successfully insert a document using the db.collection.insert() statement in my mongo shell However, the mongo shell does not return the WriteResult object.

Do I need to set this as a configuration? I watched few tutorial but it never mentioned of any.

Comment: Sounds like your MongoDB shell or server is a lower version than 2.6. Things changed in MongoDB 2.6.

Comment: this happens in my 3.2